# Flutter: Positioning images

Tags: flutter

This is the screen that I want to create:

[image]

As you can see I have got two photo in the center, how can I move this background pink image in the top left corner?

Here's a link to my full code https://pastebin.com/CwgsPx4a

```
children: <Widget> [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 250,
                
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/logo.png",
                    
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  )
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  
                  
                
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/top.png",
                    
                    
                    
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  )
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
    Column(
      children: [
        // fake top image
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        // fake logo
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        // fake other widgets
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 30,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 30,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I didn't explained it well.. As you can see on screenshot i want everything to be still in center only that 1/4 circle want to be in the top right corner i tried recoding it but i can't get it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I can't get your idea :(

Comment: Can you draw a draft? Maybe I can help.

Comment: This is how i want to look alike i think you will understand now.. 
Because i can't post directly screenshot i will leave you a link of photo: https://imgur.com/a/mvwVypc
Also this is my whole code of it:
https://pastebin.com/BiLXSkTY

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I'll start the project again because i can't adapt other things still I'm beginner and i'm watching some tutorials.